# PHP Search for all entries in an array by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, find

So for like an hour I'am struggling with this...
I'am working with MusicBrainz api, as a result I'am trying to retrieve all releases by an artist, ColdPlay for now (Becouse he have couple releases in diffrent countries).

What I want to do is:

• Search MusicBrainz response array for a duplicate song title.

• For each of the duplicates find the countries with dates that it was released

So the response would look like this:

```
{
   "title": "Parachutes",
   "releaseDates": {
        "UK": "2010-10-10",
        "USA": "2010-10-12",
        "AU": "2010-10-20",
        "XW": "2010-11-11",
   }

}
```

instead of this: https://hastebin.com/fejazububi.php

I tried using array_filter, foreach etc.. No luck what so ever.
Do someone of you have a suggesstion for this? Thank You!

***SOLVED:***

Generated response: https://hastebin.com/ubiqasugav.php
Code:

```
        $Data = [];
        $ReleasesData = $ArtistData->releases['releases'];
        foreach ($ReleasesData as $rel) {
            if(!isset($Data[$rel['title']]['releaseDates'][$rel['country']])) {
                $Data[$rel['title']]['releaseDates'][$rel['country']] = [
                    'date' => $rel['date'],
                    'status' => $rel['status']
                ];
            }
        }

        return print_r($Data);
```

Comment: Where's the original array you're searching? Perhaps simplify with a sample data array and the result you need from that data.

Comment: Its not very hard to filter the data from the given response. Just confirm first that do you want to search for a particular song title each time, or get a complete list of all duplicates with details ?

Comment: Only getting "Notice: Array to string conversion"                                                             `$ReleasesData = $ArtistData->releases['releases'];


            $array_unique = array_unique($ReleasesData); 
            $array_diff = array_diff_assoc($ReleasesData, $array_unique);`

Comment: If you think the resolution you found would be helpful to other users, feel free to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. Otherwise, you can [delete your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through loop the simple code is:

```
$titles = array_unique(array_column($myarray, 'title'));
$result = array();
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    $releaseDates = array();
    foreach ($myarray as $event) {
        if ($event['title'] == $title) {
            $releaseDates[$event['country']] = $event['date'];
        }
    }
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $data['releaseDates'] = $releaseDates;
    $result[] = $data;
}
```